# Undefined Method 'redeemed' for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nomethoderror

I want users to be able to redeem their accounts, after they purchase them through a redemption code.

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base

    @redemption_codes = Account.where(:redeemed == false).map(&:redemption_code)
    validates :code, inclusion: { in: @redemption_codes }

end
```

Here's my create method in my `AccountsController`

```
def create
  @code = Code.new(code_params)
    @account = Account.where(redemption_code: @code)
    if @code.save
        @account.redeemed == true
      flash[:notice] = "Account Redeemed"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "This does not match any accounts"
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

After a code is saved, a user entering a redemption code, I want the `:redeemed` value of the item to  change from `false` to `true`.

I got an error, I have yet to see before

```
Undefined Method 'redeemed' for  #<ActiveRecord::Relation[]>
```

Not sure why though

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you call `Account.where(redemption_code: @code)`, that may return multiple accounts. You need to do something like `Account.where(redemption_code: @code).first` or `Account.find_by_redemption_code(@code)`.